# BeautifulSoup4 and w3lib — Why Are My Results Printing Vertically? How to Format Results in CSV Format?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

here's the code:

```
while startDate <= endDate:
    try:
        the_year = startDate.strftime('%Y')
        the_month = startDate.strftime('%B')
        the_day = startDate.strftime('%-d')
        url_template = base_url + the_year + "/" + the_month + "/" + the_day + "/"
        url = url_template
        page_two = "?page=2"
        time.sleep(1)
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'})
        content = bs(response.content, "html.parser")
        uls = content.find("div", {'class': 'sitemap-column-wrapper'}).findAll("ul", {'class': 'sitemap-list'})
        for ul in uls:
            for li in ul.find_all('li', {'class': 'sitemap-list-item'}):
                for a in li.find('a').text:
                    a = w3lib.html.remove_tags(a)
                    print(str(startDate) + ',"' + a)
        time.sleep(1)
        url = url_template + page_two
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'})
        content = bs(response.content, "html.parser")
        uls = content.find("div", {'class': 'sitemap-column-wrapper'}).findAll("ul", {'class': 'sitemap-list'})
        for ul in uls:
            for li in ul.find_all('li', {'class': 'sitemap-list-item'}):
                for a in li.find('a').text:
                    a = w3lib.html.remove_tags(a)
                    print(str(startDate) + ',"' + a)
        time.sleep(1)
        startDate += delta
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

and here are the results:

```
2020-01-01,"C
2020-01-01,"i
2020-01-01,"n
2020-01-01,"c
2020-01-01,"i
2020-01-01,"n
2020-01-01,"n
```

etc. etc.  what's going on?  what i'm trying to do is print out date and headlines in csv format:  "date, headline"

before i used ".remove_tags", i was getting a block of html code with all the headlines inside.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, had one too many loops:

```
        content = bs(response.content, "html.parser")
        uls = content.find("div", {'class': 'sitemap-column-wrapper'}).findAll("ul", {'class': 'sitemap-list'})
        for ul in uls:
            for li in ul.find_all('li', {'class': 'sitemap-list-item'}):
                li = li.find('a').text
                title = w3lib.html.remove_tags(li)
```